# Do Android Automotive OS support OpenCV OpenGL and multiple screen

Tags: android-auto, qualcomm, android-automotive

I am trying to convert the desktop app to Android Automotive OS (AAOS). I am using OpenCV DNN for object tracking. Also, I am using OpenGL to render the contents. Rendering outputs (2 full HD) must be displayed on two monitors (must be **full screen**). Also, I must send some data using serial communication. I don't have any experience with AAOS. So I can not decide to this app doable or not on AAOS. So If you have any experience with AAOS can you give me any feedback about this project. AAOS runs on Snapdragon SA8155.

Dev board link:
https://www.lantronix.com/products/sa8155p-automotive-development-platform/#tab-features

Answer (score 0):

Android Automotive supports multiple screens. And specifically this platform provides multiple video outputs.
You should check whether mentioned features are supported by provided Android distributive. Most certainly the distro is supplied by Qualcomm. In this case you need to get access to Qualcomm's documentation.